# PHP Not updating on reload

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to create a system that when i submit the form, after the page refresh it should show the new values that i get from the database. The values work well when they go into the databse but they dont show after submited, only when i refresh again. Thanks for helping

```
<?php

include("connect.php");

    $query = "SELECT * FROM `laliga`";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $id = $row['id'];
        $home = $row['home'];
        $away = $row['away'];
        $win = $row['win'];
        $draw = $row['draw'];
        $lose = $row['lose'];
    }

    echo "<h2>La Liga</h2>";

    echo $home, " - ", $away;

    if (isset($_POST) && $_POST['laliga'] == 1){
        $select = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['laliga']);
        $select = $win + $select;
        mysql_query("UPDATE laliga SET win='$select'");
    }else if (isset($_POST) && $_POST['laliga'] == 'X'){
        $select = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['laliga']);
        $select = '1';
        $select = $draw + $select;
        mysql_query("UPDATE laliga SET draw='$select'");
    }else if (isset($_POST) && $_POST['laliga'] == 2){
        $select = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['laliga']);
        $select = '1';
        $select = $lose + $select;
        mysql_query("UPDATE laliga SET lose='$select'");
    } 

    header('Location: ../laliga.php');


    ?>

    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">

        <input type="radio" name="laliga" value="1">1
        <input type="radio" name="laliga" value="X">X
        <input type="radio" name="laliga" value="2">2

        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>

    </form>

    <br/>
    <?php

    echo $home, " -> ", $win;
    echo "<br/>Barazim  -> ", $draw,"<br/>";
    echo $away, " -> ", $lose;

    ?>
```

Comment: Your code uses deprecated mysql_* functions and is vulnerable to SQL injection: POST variables are not escaped

Comment: can yu point me how to fix it

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is, the results aren't showing? where is the code to show them?

Comment: Where are you defining `$home`,`$win`,`$draw`,`$away`, and `$lose`?

Comment: @C_plus_plus_Rookie See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1

Comment: Is this PHP? You have a lot of strange syntax errors.

Comment: `$select = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['laliga']);` for some basic escape

Comment: You have not responded to feedback/questions. Doing that may inspire people's help.

Comment: @Frits van Campen yes it is php and it doesn't have errors.. not that im aware of

Comment: You will run into problems echoing content before your header redirect. Try moving `echo "<h2>La Liga</h2>";` and `echo $home, " - ", $away;` below `header('Location: ../laliga.php');` Also, make sure the relative path to your "laliga.php" file is correct. Can you describe a bit more about what goes wrong with the updated code? What do you see happen?

Comment: @showdev still same problem my friend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add:

```
header('Location: <mypage.php>');
```

After `mysql_query`.

Comment: @C_plus_plus_Rookie its weird, it should work . make sure to remove <> tags. Plus the header is in the wrong position, i said right after mysql_query, inside every if statment.

Comment: Incidentally, you can leave the `action` blank, causing the page to post to itself: `action=""`.

Comment: this is a quick fix if you don't mind having longer page load times.

Answer (score 1):

You should handle all of the post data at the top of the PHP file, whilst the header function will solve your problem it's a silly and inefficient way of approaching it. by handling the post data and updating the database first, by the time you query the database the data is there! at the moment you are trying to find the data and then adding it. does this make sense?
Good luck!